# Wifi not working on Ubuntu 16 running on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: wireless, 16.04, network-manager, raspberrypi

I have Ubuntu 16 running on a Raspberry Pi 2 with a USB wifi dongle. I have Network Manager installed, and I've registered by Wifi network with it. Running `nmcli conn` shows it's connected and has received an IP address. However, I can't ping any IPs or domains, with ping responding "Destination Host Unreachable".

If I plug in an ethernet cable, I immediately get Internet back again. I've confirmed with other devices, that my Wifi router has Internet access. What would be causing this problem?

`nmcli conn`:

```
dd-wrt1             39d34wa4-a801-4ab6-a370-e466d2845c1e  802-11-wireless  wlan0  
eth0                1dr30878-1559-4b92-a26e-d964cdf41df5  802-3-ethernet   eth0   
Wired connection 1  d2936a80-cea5-4810-b5c0-53442527ee5b  802-3-ethernet   --
```

`cat /etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried updating my firmware by running:

```
sudo rpi-update
```

and then rebooting, and now everything works. Huh.